# adf test and acf plot on multiple columns

Tags: r, plot, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to apply adf.test to all columns of a dataframe. Some columns have NA values. I would like to store the output in a vector/list/dataframe.

```
H<-data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:20,10,rep=TRUE))) 
H[c(2,3,7,9),9]<-NA
H[c(1,4,8),2]<-NA
H[c(1,2,3,4,8),4]<-NA
```

I get errors as below

```
oi<-adf.test(H,alternative="stationary")
Error in adf.test(H, alternative = "stationary") : 
  x is not a vector or univariate time series

lapply(na.omit(H),adf.test)
Error in res.sum$coefficients[2, 1] : subscript out of bounds
```

Package: tseries

Help is appreciated

Comment: akrun, i'm using tseries for adf.test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
lapply(H, function(x) adf.test(x[!is.na(x)], 
           alternative='stationary', k=0))
```